# Validar input tipo numerico?

Tags: html, css

Como validar un campo tipo numerico para que no me acepte el signo menos (-) ni el signo mas (+). porque solo me acepta numeros pero entre numeros tambien acepta + y menos

Comment: Alcides, un consejo cuando preguntes, trata de anexar el código de lo que hayas tratado, es importante para darte más opciones o que los desarrolladores te ayuden a corregir el código.

Answer (score 12):

Puedes validar mediante Javascript que únicamente acepte valores numéricos:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'/>
```

Agrego un demo:

```js
function validaNumericos(event) {
    if(event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57){
      return true;
     }
     return false;        
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress='return validaNumericos(event)'/>
```

---

Tenemos el caso en el cual un usuario puede pegar texto y no solo introducirlo, por lo tanto tenemos que estar preparados para eso y no permitir introducir o pegar texto que no sea de tipo numérico :

```js
function validaNumericos(){
 var inputtxt = document.getElementById('text'); 
 var valor = inputtxt.value;
 for(i=0;i<valor.length;i++){
     var code=valor.charCodeAt(i);
         if(code<=48 || code>=57){          
           inputtxt.value=""; 
           return;
         }    
   }
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" onblur="validaNumericos();" />
```

---

```js
onload = function(){ 
  var ele = document.querySelectorAll('.validanumericos')[0];
  ele.onkeypress = function(e) {
     if(isNaN(this.value+String.fromCharCode(e.charCode)))
        return false;
  }
  ele.onpaste = function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
   
<input class="validanumericos" type=text />
```

---

Otra versión pero ahora usando **JQuery**

```js
$(function(){

  $('.validanumericos').keypress(function(e) {
 if(isNaN(this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.charCode))) 
     return false;
  })
  .on("cut copy paste",function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="validanumericos" type=text />
```

Existe una **[respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31091122/250260)** de @vinayakj con otras opciones el sitio en inglés.

Comment: Con esto aún se pueden pegar valores que contengan valores inválidos, ¿me equivoco?

Comment: Lo que realiza es que únicamente permite teclear eventos de código 48 al 57 que comprende 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 http://keycode.info/

Comment: claro, pero yo puedo escribir lo que quiera en el bloc de notas, copiarlo y pegarlo en el input, ¿no?

Comment: tienes razón, agregué una versión mejorada.

Comment: +1 entonces ;) Un saludo.

Comment: igualmente amigo, de hecho aprovecho para felicitarte, creo que pocos lo saben pero gracias a tí como principal impulsor tenemos esta comunidad en idioma español @jachguate un gran saludo!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48754/discussion-between-jachguate-and-elenasys).

Comment: Agregaste mi respuesta @Elenasys :( , soy yo o la primera opción y la segunda permite entrada de letras y además de pegar valores? . la del Jquery funciona perfecto.

Comment: La segunda permite introducir texto, pero al perder el enfoque del text elimina el contenido.

Answer (score 2):

Para validar el tipo de campo es number y el mínimo quíta negativos.

```
<input type="number" min="0" step="1"/>
```

Necesitas una expresión regular para validar solo numeros algo como `[0-9]`, lo siguiente valida un número de 10 dígitos pero la última validación debe ser en lenguaje server side.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{10}" />
```

Si quieres usar JavaScript entonces **NO USES JQUERY** si tu proyecto no está usando la librería para otra cosa.
Las tareas simples se solucionan sin cargar una librería enorme para ello.

Básicamente necesitas agregar una función al presionar una tecla, al enviar una forma o al darle click al submit:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="validar_campo()">
```

---

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" onsubmit="return validar_campo()">
```

Ahora la función;

```
function validar_campo(evento){
 evento.value = evento.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"");
}
```

Algo más simple en la misma línea ([respuesta de @Max](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12927999/1684426)):

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="if ( isNaN( String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) )) return false;" />
```

Comment: Amig@, Un comentario el input debe ser de tipo "number" :  <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]{10}" /> para que funcione =)

Comment: @Elenasys No, las expresiones regulares solo funcionan con text, date, search, url, tel, email y password.

Comment: Usar RegEx es excelente pero prueba <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{10}" /> y <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]{10}" /> y veras que funciona diferente, por cierto si funciona con tipo "number", pero tal vez en algún tipo de navegador no, podría ser.

Comment: Debe funcionar en algunos browsers (me imagino) por compatibilidad pero el standard es solo los tipos que menciono, principalmente porque no tiene caso usarlo en `number` principalmente porque los atributos `min` y `max` se encargan de esto, hablando de HTML5 de cualquier forma :)